# DKIM wrong body hash using Perl CPAN Mail::DKIM::Signer

Tags: perl, dkim

I have a script that is sending emails via SMTP and I'm trying to get it to sign emails with a DKIM signature using CPAN's Mail::DKIM::Signer. The trouble is I am getting error that the body hash is invalid. For example I sent the email below to the port25.com verifier and it is telling me the body hash it expected is "QFBPfFyqSONobf7fNoeeGl652WY=" but my signature says "qUFULrL5rN08Illvd85ZYXxgNNk=".

My DNS record is         "k=rsa; t=s; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDs5BnRmpNH0Pz6B02+z
F2GuLm7ahrEXu6zB3WgxySbAGT8v9rpzI7ePhXhxo/RMXR9p5IYtzmBJ0NTjNLDKRFeSOMTeRdDi8DnO
4gUxKyT3v31IvS0+1ZZH2Sj404uv/jg2TKNinIU4/v+pM4ImLZ8uIXsEXRFgGhwKTjTJRNX0QIDAQAB"

Is anyone able to shed some light onto why recipients (including yahoo & port25) are expecting a different body hash? Something to do with the way it's encoded?

```
This is a MIME encoded message.

--=_b4326086ed9a1ae338d4dabe6b015dde
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hi this is a test of DKIM. Bye!

--=_b4326086ed9a1ae338d4dabe6b015dde
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css">
body,td,th { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; color: #000000; }
body { background-color: #3895CB; margin: 0px 20px; text-align:center; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hi this a test of <b>DKIM</b>. Bye!
</body>
</html>

--=_b4326086ed9a1ae338d4dabe6b015dde--
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

dos2unix on the email before signing it did the trick.

Does that means the problem was with carriage returns or something?

Comment: Who knows? You didn't show the Perl code you use, so it's only possible to speculate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used '\n' as newline.

Chaning this to '\r\n' solved the problem.